# Using TortoiseHg to push to an authenticated git repository

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisehg

I'm trying to push a changeset from a local Mercurial repository created with TortoiseHg to a remote Git repository. I have hg-git installed and configured and it will pull just fine. But when I run the push it gives me this

*Command*

```
hg push git+ssh://git@dummyrepo:username/repo.git
```

*Result*

```
pushing to git+ssh://git@dummyrepo:username/repo.git
importing Hg objects into Git
creating and sending data
abort: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

There are several things I've done to get to this point. But I'm hoping to resolve this last thing because I find TortoiseHg to be much easier to work with than any of the Git tools out there (for windows.)

- Installed TortoiseHg
- Pulled down the hg-git from http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/
- Configured mercurial.ini to point to the hg-git library
- Pulled down dulwich source from git://git.samba.org/jelmer/dulwich.git
- Compiled dulwich and put it into library.zip for TortoiseHg
- Configured TortoiseHg to use TortoisePlink.exe for ssh
- Added my private key to Pageant

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the very same issue. After reading this post, I just made a copy of plink.exe, renamed it to ssh.exe and placed it on my Windows PATH. Works great.

Note: I have msysGit installed to use Git Bash only, so if you have Git installed for Windows CLI, then this might not be a good idea since the two ssh binary's *might* clash.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure Dulwich to use plink.exe instead of ssh.exe (OpenSSH) ?

I just hacked my copy of Dulwich directly:

client.py:

```
    def connect_ssh(self, host, command, username=None, port=None):
    #FIXME: This has no way to deal with passwords..
    args = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\plink.exe', '-x', '-batch']
```

Also, you have to make 1 connection via PuTTY to cache the git servers public key first.

Answer (score 0):

What does wireshark have to say?  Can you provide a dump of the tcp connection that comes from hg?  Most likely, the guys in #mercurial on freenode in irc will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check out #mercurial to see if they are any help. As for the TCP dump I can run wireshark but I'm not sure what I would provide that would be helpful from there. I see the ssh communication going through.

Comment: @nathan ah yeah, wasn't thinking about the ssh part.  wireshark will be useless there, but you might consider running `hg push --debug ...` or `hg push -e 'ssh -vvv` --debug ...`.  Not sure if either will help, but it may shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

I later found out that the answer to my problem was that the git server I was using had a quota set for me and I was over the quota. It's too bad that I didn't get a better error message. Once I contacted their customer service they let me know. I was able to push after this was resolved.